# com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.load IllegalArgumentException by url=null

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, object-storage

[The sample program](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries/java.html#java)

```
package bluemixtest;

import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;
import com.ibm.oauth.BasicIBMOAuthCredentials;
import java.util.List;

public class BlueMixTest {

private static AmazonS3 _s3Client;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SDKGlobalConfiguration.IAM_ENDPOINT = "https://iam.bluemix.net/oidc/token";

    String bucketName = "********";
    String api_key = "********";
    String service_instance_id = "********";
    String endpoint_url = "https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net";
    String location = "us";

    _s3Client = createClient(api_key, service_instance_id, endpoint_url, location);
    listObjects(bucketName, _s3Client);
    listBuckets(_s3Client);
}

public static AmazonS3 createClient(String api_key, String service_instance_id, String endpoint_url, String location) {
    AWSCredentials credentials;
    if (endpoint_url.contains("objectstorage.softlayer.net")) {
        credentials = new BasicIBMOAuthCredentials(api_key, service_instance_id);
    } else {
        String access_key = api_key;
        String secret_key = service_instance_id;
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key, secret_key);
    }
    ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration().withRequestTimeout(5000);
    clientConfig.setUseTcpKeepAlive(true);

    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(endpoint_url, location)).withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
            .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig).build();
    return s3Client;
}

public static void listObjects(String bucketName, AmazonS3 s3Client) {
    System.out.println("Listing objects in bucket " + bucketName);
    ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName));
    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
        System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " + "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + ")");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void listBuckets(AmazonS3 s3Client) {
    System.out.println("Listing buckets");
    final List<Bucket> bucketList = _s3Client.listBuckets();
    for (final Bucket bucket : bucketList) {
        System.out.println(bucket.getName());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}


ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration()
```

IllegalArgumentException

StackTrace:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.loadfrom(InternalConfig.java:235)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.load(InternalConfig.java:249)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig$Factory.(InternalConfig.java:304)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:142)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:137)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:100)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.(ClientConfiguration.java:65)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:142)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:137)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:100)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.(ClientConfiguration.java:65)
>     at bluemixtest.BlueMixTest.createClient(BlueMixTest.java:58)    at
>   bluemixtest.BlueMixTest.main(BlueMixTest.java:44) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.loadfrom(InternalConfig.java:235)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.load(InternalConfig.java:249)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig$Factory.(InternalConfig.java:304)
>
> ibm-cos-java-sdk-core-1.1.0 and ibm-cos-java-sdk-s3-1.1.0

I want to solve this problem.
Resource from field: ibm-cos-java-sdk

I want to access IBM Cloud Object Storage using ibm-cos-java-sdk.

Comment: Please be sure to fully explain what the actual problem and objective are -- as well as what you've already tried -- rather than assuming that we will figure it out. Otherwise you'll probably get fewer useful answers than hoped for.

Comment: thanks,I want to access IBM Cloud Object Storage using ibm-cos-java-sdk.

Comment: maven project was not created Normally.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are not using right dependencies for the code.

If you are using maven, please put the following dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.cos</groupId>
        <artifactId>ibm-cos-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: pom.xml was provided by IBM.
The version is 1.1.0.
I do not use JUNIT.
need dependency 1.0.1?

Comment: maven project was reated Normally